# fetch a row with same name in the request sql

Tags: php, sql

i can't fetch a two row with same name correctly.
That s my table "equipes"

[image]

and that s my table "confrontations"
[image]

that s my code

> ```
>    $semaine = $item['semaine'];
>    $query = " SELECT *
>     FROM confrontations
>     LEFT OUTER JOIN equipes
>     ON confrontations.id_equipe1 = equipes.id_equipe
>     WHERE semaine = :semaine
>     UNION
>     SELECT *
>     FROM confrontations
>     LEFT OUTER JOIN equipes
>     ON confrontations.id_equipe2 = equipes.id_equipe   
>     WHERE semaine = :semaine2";
>     $check = $pdo->prepare($query);
>     $check->bindParam(':semaine', $semaine, PDO::PARAM_INT);
>     $check->bindParam(':semaine2', $semaine, PDO::PARAM_INT);
>     $check->execute();
> ```

I would like print like:
Bologne - Genoa
Naples - Hellas Verone
Inter Milan - Lazio
...

but if i try to do this, i get:

```
> $rows = $check->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
>         foreach ($rows as $row){
>             echo $row['libelle_equipe'] . "<br>" . $row['libelle_equipe'];
>         }
```

[image]

***How can i get and print correctly the versus match?***

Answer (score 1):

You should join two time the table equipe ..

```
    SELECT a.*, e1.libelle_equipe equipe1, e2.libelle_equipe equipe2
    FROM confrontations a
    INNER JOIN equipes e1 ON a.id_equipe1 = e1.id_equipe
    INNER JOIN equipes e2 ON a.id_equipe2 = e2.id_equipe
    WHERE a.semaine = :semaine
```

..

```
    foreach ($rows as $row){
         echo $row['equipe1'] . " - " . $row['equipe2'] .  "<br>";
    }
```

obviously  Atalanta win all the matches ..